# stacking multiple traits in akka Actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor, traits

I'm creating multiple traits which extend Actor. Then I want to create an actor class which uses some of these traits. However, I'm not sure how to combine the receive methods from all traits in the receive method of the Actor class.

Traits:

```
 trait ServerLocatorTrait extends Actor {
    def receive() = {
      case "s" => println("I'm server ")
    }
  }

  trait ServiceRegistrationTrait extends Actor {
    def receive() = {
      case "r" => println("I'm registration ")
    }
  }
```

The Actor:

```
class FinalActor extends Actor with ServiceRegistrationTrait with ServerLocatorTrait {
  override def receive = {
     super.receive orElse ??? <--- what to put here
  }
}
```

Now if I send `"r"` and `"s"` to `FinalActor` it goes only in `ServerLocatorTrait` - which is the last trait added.
So the way this works right now is that it considers super the last trait added, so in this case `ServerLocatorTrait`

**Question**:
How do I combine the receive methods from all the traits in `FinalActor`?

PS - I've seen the actors with `react` example: http://www.kotancode.com/2011/07/19/traits-multiple-inheritance-and-actors-in-scala/
but it's not what I need

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala stackable trait pattern with Akka actors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124643/scala-stackable-trait-pattern-with-akka-actors)

Comment: @cmbaxter I don't see how it could be a duplicate of that. Though maybe that OP could use what I chose as the solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can combine the receive methods, since that would involve calling the super's super to obtain the `ServiceRegistration`'s `receive` method. It would also be very confusing.

Another way would be to give different names to the `receive` method in the traits.

```
trait ServerLocatorTrait extends Actor {
  def handleLocation: Receive = {
    case "s" => println("I'm server ")
  }
}

trait ServiceRegistrationTrait extends Actor {
  def handleRegistration: Receive = {
    case "r" => println("I'm registration ")
  }
}

class FinalActor extends Actor with ServiceRegistrationTrait with ServerLocatorTrait {
  def receive = handleLocation orElse handleRegistration
}

object Main extends App {

  val sys = ActorSystem()

  val actor = sys.actorOf(Props(new FinalActor))

  actor ! "s"
  actor ! "r"

  sys.shutdown()

}
```

You can still use you initial approach, but you must chain the `super.receive` for each mixed trait.

```
trait IgnoreAll extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = Map()
}

trait ServerLocatorTrait extends Actor {
  abstract override def receive = ({
    case "s" => println("I'm server ")
  }: Receive) orElse super.receive
}

trait ServiceRegistrationTrait extends Actor {
  abstract override def receive = ({
    case "r" => println("I'm registration ")
  }: Receive) orElse super.receive
}

class FinalActor extends IgnoreAll with ServiceRegistrationTrait with ServerLocatorTrait
```

The latter solution looks pretty ugly to me.

Please see the below link for a more detailed discussion on the subject:

> [Extending Actors using PartialFunction chaining](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/actors.html#Extending_Actors_using_PartialFunction_chaining)

Comment: I like your first solution and I think I will be using that (it shows more of what's going on); I was initially looking for something like your second solution.

Comment: Your traits could be declared as: trait ServerLocatorTrait { this: Actor => .... }, because they are not actual actors by themselves. With this syntax you say "This trait will be mixed in to an Actor".