# When inheriting from a base actor, how to add to the receive matches?

Tags: akka

I have a base actor that has receive matchers already:

class BaseActor() extends Actor {
  def receive =  {
   ..
  }
}

Now when I extend it, how do I add more partial functions to the receive?

```
class UserActor() extends BaseActor {

}
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? think of actors as microservices, they do one thing and do it good. It's better same actor handles same message, composition over inheritance applies too

Comment: It is a BaseActor, a template, it is not being used elsewhere.

Comment: if you want to inherit is because you want to share code at least more than one class right? if you don't do that, don't extend. But if you really want to go that way http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/actors.html#Extending_Actors_using_PartialFunction_chaining

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stacking multiple traits in akka Actors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468845/stacking-multiple-traits-in-akka-actors)