# Is ComposableActor in Akka poor design?

Tags: scala, akka

I recently found [a description of how to use ComposableActor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126433/6296589) to lazily build *receive* for composite actors.  The suggested solution seem to address my use case.  I see this as a neat way to couple a traditional trait/interface with an Actor, which can ease correct implementation.  The ComposableActor trait was originally described [in the docs themselves](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.5/AkkaScala.pdf), but have now (in v. 2.4.17) been replaced with, "Instead of inheritance the same pattern can be applied via composition - one would simply compose the receive method using partial functions from delegates."

I am curious what may have motivated the removal of ComposableActor from the recent docs -- is the prior approach/implementation somehow not desirable?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/rkuhn/blog/blob/master/02_composing_actor_behavior.md and the talk from Aleksandar Prokopec in Scala Days https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lulYWWD4Qo I´m pretty sure they will help you

Comment: Helpful.  I think it is fair to say that ComposableActor represented an intermediate step toward typed processes.  ComposableActor can create situations in which colliding branches of the receive partial function are obfuscated to the programmer.