# Akka actor inheritance with context.become

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe

I have a tricky issue when trying to change a child actor's state with the `become` method. I implemented actor inheritance as per the `Receiving` trait suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124643/how-to-use-stackable-trait-pattern-with-akka-actors):

```
trait Mcma extends Receiving with ActorLogging {
  val actorName: String

  /**
    * Simple method to be overridden when necessary
    * @param entity the response entity
    */
  protected def handleHttpOK(entity: ResponseEntity): Unit = log.info(s"$actorName got unhandled OK response")

  // Add http responses match if necessary
  receiver {
    case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, entity, _) => handleHttpOK(entity)

    case resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
      log.error(s"$actorName got response code: {}", code)
      // Discard the flow to avoid backpressure
      resp.discardEntityBytes()

    case e: Status.Failure => log.error(s"$actorName got failure: {}", e.cause.getMessage)

    case _ => log.warning(s"Unexpected message in $actorName")
  }
}
```

The problem occurs when I have an actor that implements this `Mcma` trait and changes its own state with the `become` pattern:

```
class Reseau(url: String, optSender: Option[ActorRef]) extends Mcma with Receiving {
  override val actorName: String = "ReseauActor"

  /**
    * The active method used to handle actor state change with the become helper
    * @param queryDataStr the query string for each call to ReseauActor
    * @return
    */
  def active(queryDataStr: String): Receive = {
    case s: String => context become active(s)
  }

  // Init the actor with empty query
  receiver(
    active("")
  )
}
```

Once the context has changed, the default inherited matching cases like `e` or `_` are not matched anymore. There is most likely an obvious issue...

**[Updated working version with answer from Evgeny]**
With the mentioned `Receiving` trait,
Reseau actor becomes

```
class Reseau(url: String, optSender: Option[ActorRef]) extends Mcma {
  override val actorName: String = "ReseauActor"

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    super.preStart()
    // Init the actor with empty query
    context become receiver(active(""))
  }

  /**
    * The active method used to handle actor state change with the become helper
    *
    * @param queryDataStr the query string for each call to ReseauActor
    * @return
    */
  def active(queryDataStr: String): Receive = {

    case s: String => context become receiver(active(s))
  }
}
```

and the `Mcma` trait:

```
trait Mcma extends Receiving with ActorLogging {
  val actorName: String

  /**
    * Simple method to be overridden when necessary
    * @param entity the response entity
    */
  protected def handleHttpOK(entity: ResponseEntity): Unit = log.info(s"$actorName got unhandled OK response")

  // For http response handling
  final implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(context.system))

  override def preStart(): Unit = log.info(s"$actorName started")

  override def postStop(): Unit = log.info(s"$actorName stopped")

  // Add http responses match if necessary
  addReceiver {
    case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, entity, _) => handleHttpOK(entity)

    case resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
      log.error(s"$actorName got response code: {}", code)
      // Discard the flow to avoid backpressure
      resp.discardEntityBytes()

    case e: Status.Failure => log.error(s"$actorName got failure: {}", e.cause.getMessage)

    case _ => log.warning(s"Unexpected message in $actorName")
  }
}
```

and in order to define an actor that would not need to change his internal state, you would just do:

```
class TLRVJob1() extends Mcma {
  override val actorName: String = "TLRVJob1Actor"

  addReceiver {
    case t: Get => ???
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to modify initial `Receiving` trait:

```
trait Receiving extends Actor {
  var receivers: Receive = Actor.emptyBehavior
  def addReceiver(next: Actor.Receive): Unit = {receivers = receiver(next)}
  def receiver(next: Actor.Receive): Receive = {receivers orElse next}

  def receive: Receive = receivers
}
```

Now, you have two cases, to add permanent part of receive and have class-dependent part for become. Change `receiver` with `addReceiver` in hierarchy, and init your `Reseau` class: instead of

```
receiver(
  active("")
)
```

move this into `preStart` in form:

```
override def preStart(): Unit = {
  super.preStart()
  context become receiver(active(""))
}
```

and change `active` method body to

```
context become receiver(active(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest fix in this case is to forgo the use of `become`. That is, instead of encoding the `queryDataStr` state as a parameter, change `queryDataStr` to a `var`:

```
class Reseau(url: String, optSender: Option[ActorRef]) extends Mcma with Receiving {
  override val actorName: String = "ReseauActor"

  var queryDataStr: Option[String] = None

  receiver {
    case s: String => queryDataStr = Option(s)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed I thought of that solution but preferred to try to keep the functional state change approach.